# Spring security authentication: always redirect to error login page

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

I have problem with spring security login on my application.
My login page is on seller/login url, processing url is set to /loginProcessing, after submit login data on form:

```
    <form name="loginform" action="/loginProcessing" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am always redirected to login error page with status 302 on loginProcessing, no matter if the login and password are correct.
Do you know why it happens every time?
Sql queries in spring-security.xml for checking login data looks correct, passwords in database are stored as plain text
[image]

my configuration files:

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/seller/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/customer/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/changePassword" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- user-defined login form redirection -->
    <form-login login-page="/seller/login" login-processing-url="/loginProcessing" default-target-url="/main"
                username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"
                authentication-failure-url="/seller/login/error" />

    <!-- logout url -->
    <logout logout-success-url="/seller/login/logout" />

    <!-- csrf disabled -->
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query=
                                   "select email,password from users where email=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query=
                                   "select u.email, r.name from users u, role r, user_roles ur where u.id = ur.user_id and ur.roles_id = r.id and u.email =?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="application"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"/>
<import resource="classpath:spring-security.xml" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="application"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/khn"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>
```

servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app  version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>khn</display-name>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: In request payload i have "username: admin4
password: password
submit: Submit", in response tab in chrome dev tools i have "failed to load respnse data". Every time i have redirection to login-error page, no matter that credential is valid or no

Comment: maybe its problem with password encryption? I stored passwords in database without any encryption, is good approach?

Comment: Spring v. 5.2.3, spring security v5.2.2, my whole repository: https://github.com/mtpx/khn/tree/spring_security

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i find answer by myself.
I missed some schemas declaration in spring-security.xml and servlet.xml

Now in servlet.xml i have:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

and in spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
```

Also i edited users-by-username-query, this query needs additional enabled column

```
select email,password,1 as enabled from users where email=?
```

Now we can log in with valid credentials

Comment: Why are you not using Spring Boot? It will reduce boilerplate configuration.